# Intel Skylake HD 530 Graphics and Ubuntu 16.10 - No video / HDMI Out

Tags: nvidia, graphics, hdmi, intel, gpu-driver

I have an MSI GS43VR laptop with Nvidia GTX 1060 and Intel HD 530 graphics. I am not using the Nvidia card nor do I have the proprietary Nvidia drivers installed. Whenever I install the Nvidia driver, I can use the Nvidia graphics card but as soon as I switch to the Intel card in PRIME, I get a black screen and lockup. Video out works on Nvidia but then the fans are running almost at full speed and very loud.

I would like to use the Intel graphics exclusively while using Ubuntu (I have Windows for the heavy lifting and gaming) but video out simply refuses to run on this laptop. I have tried everything: all the different versions of kernels Xanmod, official Ubuntu 4.6, 4.7 and 4.9 and Padoka's PPA for Intel drivers. Nothing works. Whether I use the mini display port or HDMI, no video out on the Intel side whatsoever. I am at my wits end. I need an external display to do my job and my vision is slightly impaired now as well.

Does anyone have a solution to get external video out working on this Intel HD 530 graphics card??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

According to [the NotebookReview MSI GS43VR Owners’ Lounge](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/msi-gs43vr-phantom-pros-owners-lounge.793376/page-77#post-10386421) all of the external ports (HDMI, DP, Thunderbolt 3) are hard-wired to the Nvidia card, so I’m affraid it’s not possible to use the Intel card to drive an external monitor.

Comment: Are you trying to answer the question ?